# how to solve /wd/hub/session java.io.IOException: when running Robot framework testcases on selenium grid in docker?

Tags: python, selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am trying to run my robot scripts on docker remotely with selenium grid. The script to call the docker is

```
Open Browser Remotely
    [Arguments]    ${URL}    ${DOCKER_IP}
    ${REMOTE_URL}                   Catenate    ${DOCKER_IP}/wd/hub  
    Open Browser                    ${URL}      
    ...                             ${BROWSER}
    ...                             None
    ...                             remote_url=${REMOTE_URL}
```

when i run the docker test case i get the following error in the docker log.

```
hub_1       | 2018-06-21 14:15:27.069:WARN:osjs.HttpChannel:qtp615634843-17: /wd/hub/session java.io.IOException: org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: Cannot extract a capabilities from the request: {"capabilities": {"alwaysMatch": {"platform": "ANY", "browserName": "chrome", "version": ""}, "firstMatch": []}, "desiredCapabilities": {"platform": "ANY", "browserName": "chrome", "version": ""}}
```

In the robot Message log no errors, just a vague message

```
 20180621 19:45:27.060 : INFO : Cannot capture screenshot because no browser is open.
20180621 19:45:27.066 : FAIL : WebDriverException: Message:
```

The other part is that my colleague is able to run his test in the docker.
please let me know how to solve this issue. Do let me know if more info to added.

Comment: Can you add some more information about your setup? For example the versions of RF, Selenium, Pyhton/Java, Selenium Grid etc.

Comment: @A.Kootstra  I was checking my version and just did an upgrade on the version of like RF and Selenium, tried running my scripts and it started working for me. Thanks a lot for the tip